# Sintaxis base de datos

Tags: mysql, webservice

he generado un `script` en **mysql** y al fina de lo dicho antes aparece

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

El problema es que esto se genera al usar **mysql workbench**
pero al momento de añadir esto a la consola del servidor web arroja error

```
SET SQL_MODE = @OLD_SQL_MODE ;


MySQL ha dicho:

#1231 - Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NULL' `
```

**Codigo SQL**

```
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `u268055042_santo`.`VOTACIONPREGUNTA`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u268055042_santo`.`VOTACIONPREGUNTA` (
  `idVOTACIONPREGUNTA` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MUYDEACUERDO` INT NOT NULL,
  `DESACUERDO` INT NOT NULL,
  `ENDESACUERDO` INT NOT NULL,
  `NOMEINTERESA` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVOTACIONPREGUNTA`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `u268055042_santo`.`ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u268055042_santo`.`ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO` (
  `ASISTENTE_idASISTENTE` INT NOT NULL,
  `EVENTO_idEVENTO` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ASISTENTE_idASISTENTE`, `EVENTO_idEVENTO`),
  INDEX `fk_ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO_EVENTO1_idx` (`EVENTO_idEVENTO` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO_ASISTENTE_idx` (`ASISTENTE_idASISTENTE` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO_ASISTENTE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ASISTENTE_idASISTENTE`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`ASISTENTE` (`idASISTENTE`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ASISTENTE_has_EVENTO_EVENTO1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EVENTO_idEVENTO`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`EVENTO` (`idEVENTO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `u268055042_santo`.`EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u268055042_santo`.`EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR` (
  `EVENTO_idEVENTO` INT NOT NULL,
  `EXPOSITOR_idEXPOSITOR` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EVENTO_idEVENTO`, `EXPOSITOR_idEXPOSITOR`),
  INDEX `fk_EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR_EXPOSITOR1_idx` (`EXPOSITOR_idEXPOSITOR` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR_EVENTO1_idx` (`EVENTO_idEVENTO` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR_EVENTO1`

       FOREIGN KEY (`EVENTO_idEVENTO`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`EVENTO` (`idEVENTO`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EVENTO_has_EXPOSITOR_EXPOSITOR1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EXPOSITOR_idEXPOSITOR`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`EXPOSITOR` (`idEXPOSITOR`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

alguien tiene alguna idea si es necesario agregar estas lineas puesto que ya he creado las tablas sin problemas. saludos !

Answer (score 1):

```
@OLD_SQL_MODE;
@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Son parámetros que añade el workbech. Por ejemplo:

```
SET FOREIG_KEYS_CHECKS = 1;
```

Si quieres usarlas en las consultas debes mirar que valor les asigna el workbench. Mira en la documentación de MySql el valor por defecto.

[Aquí](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/set_foreign_key_checks) tienes un ejemplo.

Comment: Pero esto sirve para actualizar las tablas si se cambian los campos?

Comment: Son variables generales de ejecución, si por ejemplo `SET FOREIGN_KEYS_CHECKS=0;`, no verificará las relaciones de clave foranea. Si no has cambiado nada de la configuración del workbenck seguramente puedes eliminarlar del query.

Comment: eso queria saber, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

ese codigo generado esta desordenado pone los Set al final de tu script

```
#1231 - Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NULL' `
```

no puedes anadir algun valor por que aun no existe el campo

no es necesario poner ese codigo

Comment: este código se genero automáticamente al procesar la base en mysql workbench y importe el .sql al webservice ...

Comment: @FelixBeeb primero pon el codigo de las tablas y luego lo demas, es decir primero hace correr el codigo de las tablas

Comment: Eso hice y me arrojo el error si creo las tablas

Comment: @FelixBeeb puedes poner tu codigo en tu pregunta?

Comment: Lo he agregado ...

Comment: @FelixBeeb no es necesario poner ese codigo,

Comment: @FelixBeeb debes marcar bien si alguna respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema